# React one item's loading shows in every item in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a react page where I show all FAQs items in a list within a javascript map loop. There are two buttons yes or no. Users can vote an answer yes or no. So whenever the user clicks the buttons a loading indicator will show.

Faqs Page:

```
<>
{
faqs.map((faq) => (
 <Faq key={faq.id} faq={faq} />
))
}
</>
```

Faq component:

```
interface IProps {
  faq: IFaq;
}

const FaqVoteSection: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const { faq } = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { faqVoteLoading } = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user);

  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState<
    'yesvote-loading' | 'novote-loading' | 'not-loading'
  >('not-loading');

  const onVoteSubmit = async (vote: boolean) => {
    if (faq) {
      dispatch(
        faqVoteApiAction({
          faq_id: faq.id,
          vote,
        })
      );
      setLoadingState('not-loading');
    }
  };

  const onYesVotePress = () => {
    setLoadingState('yesvote-loading');
    onVoteSubmit(true);
  };

  const onNoVotePress = async () => {
    setLoadingState('novote-loading');
    await onVoteSubmit(false);
  };

  return (
    <FlexContainer>
      <SolidButton
        type={faq.vote === 'yes' ? 'primary' : 'default'}
        size="small"
        onClick={onYesVotePress}
        loading={loadingState === 'yesvote-loading' && faqVoteLoading}
      >
        Yes
      </SolidButton>
      <Gap />
      <SolidButton
        size="small"
        type={faq.vote === 'no' ? 'primary' : 'default'}
        onClick={onNoVotePress}
        loading={loadingState === 'novote-loading' && faqVoteLoading}
      >
        No
      </SolidButton>
    </FlexContainer>
  );
};
```

Now when I click a vote button I want to show the loading only for that item. But the loading shows every item in the list. I think it's because of the map loop.

[image]

Comment: Try adding an `await` before the `dispatch` call (`await dispatch(..)`) so that you don't call `setLoadingState('not-loading');` until after the API call has finished.  There are some other things I might change here, but that alone I think will fix it.

Comment: Having the same problem right now. One way would be to save the loading-state for each faq on the faq itself. Seems overkill to me tho. Please share if a better solution is found

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and should work for everyone.

Solution:

Instead of setting `yesvote-loading` in the state keep faq `_id` on the state.

```
const [loadingId, setLoadingId] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

 const onYesVotePress = (faqId) => {
      setLoadingState(faqId);
      onVoteSubmit(true);
  };

return (
<FlexContainer>
  <SolidButton
    type={faq.vote === 'yes' ? 'primary' : 'default'}
    size="small"
    onClick={onYesVotePress}
    loading={faqVoteLoading && loadingId === faq._id}
  >
    Yes
  </SolidButton>      
</FlexContainer>
);
```